# How do I drag a text box in Preview?

Tags: pdf, mouse, preview, text

When using Preview, I can create a text box to add text on top of a PDF. However, the text box is not always created in the correct area. I find that I can use the Arrow Keys to move the text box. Or, I can stretch the text box with my mouse and pointer. However, I cannot move the text box using my mouse. What am I missing? How do I do that?

Apple's reference says, "To move the text box, just drag it." But, I haven't figured out how to do that.

Comment: I just tried my answer again and it's correct and very repeatable.  Move cursor over text box and click,  The cursor should turn into a hand and you can move the text box!

Comment: I assume you refer to the answer below. For me, it still doesn't work. I can move with the arrow keys, but not click and drag with the hand. The hand moves, but the text box doesn't move. I can also drag the sides of the text box if I selection, but not the entire box. I'm running 10.14; perhaps it's fixed in Catalina. Or, maybe a trick that is intuitive but I just don't understand.

By the way, it is not only the text box. If I draw an oval or another shape, I can also not drag that.

Answer (score 1):

[image: macOS Preview - Drag Text Box]

Move the mouse cursor over the Text box and the cursor should change to hand icon. When it does, simply drag the Text box.

Answer (score 0):

You select the text box and then position the cursor over the center of the text box. Now left-click your mouse button and wait a second or two. The cursor should turn into a closed fist and then you can move the whole text box.

Comment: RE: "Now left-click your mouse button and wait a second or two." - It's actually a left-click-hold and drag not just a left-click and if you're having to wait a second or two, then something is not right. I can left-click-hold and start dragging it as quick as I preformed the left-click-hold.

Comment: yes, its probably due to my failing machine.  Everything is slow. It takes a second for the machine to realize the cursor is in the box.

Comment: Thanks. With the "hand" (not a closed fist), I can use the arrow keys to move the text box. But, I cannot drag the text box. I was another post that indicated it may be due to my older Wacom tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I find that BOTH techniques work.  I've been trying to create a genealogy pedigree pdf (which I can't find in an electronic version of anywhere), so I had a copy of the LDS form scanned and used that to create my own.  I was going NUTS over the proclivity of Preview to align text boxes across the page even when the alignment didn't work for the pre-drawn lines.

Using the hand mouse version works fairly well to move a good distance, but the auto alignment sometimes just screwed things up - but using the ARROW keys gets me the fine tuning I need to overcome that automatic alignment.

So, it's good to know both work!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/329856)